# Scrolling in CursorAdapter leads to crash application

Tags: android

I need to get id of item that had been clicking. So in bindView I set id to viewHolder via holder.layout.setTag(id) and in onClick I get this value via view.getTag. This code work fine when I just run it but when I start scrolling it on a few items app crash and in log I can see ClassCastException javaLanString in bindView. So, without those setTag and getTag code work perfect. 
In a few hours I try to figure out why I get ClassCastException but I didn't find answer. Can you have ideas?

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    String value = cursor.getString(itemId);
    Log.i("MINE", value);
    holder.layout.setTag(value);
    holder.name.setText(cursor.getString(itemName));
    holder.country.setText(cursor.getString(itemCountry));

 @Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(com.home.R.layout.item_list_row,
            parent, false); 
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(
            (TextView) view.findViewById(com.home.R.id.item_row_name),
            (TextView) view.findViewById(com.home.R.id.item_row_population),
            (TextView) view.findViewById(com.home.R.id.item_row_country), 
            (ImageView) view.findViewById(com.home.R.id.icon), 
            (View) view.findViewById(R.id.row_item));
    view.setTag(holder);
    view.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

 private static final class ViewHolder {
    final TextView name;
    final TextView population;
    final TextView country;
    final ImageView icon;
    final View layout;

    public ViewHolder(TextView name, TextView population, TextView country,
            ImageView icon, View layout) {
        this.name = name;
        this.population = population;
        this.country = country;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.layout = layout;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I get error in this line ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag(); Below I put stacktrace that show where error happend 
    09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at com.dataart.representation.ItemsAdapter.bindView(ItemsAdapter.java:38)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:186)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1397)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.widget.ListView.addViewBelow(ListView.java:2914)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.widget.ListView.scrollListItemsBy(ListView.java:2843)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.widget.ListView.arrowScrollImpl(ListView.java:2340)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.widget.ListView.arrowScroll(ListView.java:2287)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.widget.ListView.commonKey(ListView.java:2089)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.widget.ListView.onKeyDown(ListView.java:2036)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1256)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:3855)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:787)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.widget.ListView.dispatchKeyEvent(ListView.java:2021)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1687)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1120)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2073)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1663)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2560)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2535)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1867)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-15 13:35:21.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2175):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: You need to provide the full error line from the stack trace, plus indicate where in the code listing that error is occurring, for anyone to really give you much help. Also, I have no idea why you are calling `setTag()` on `holder.layout` -- that's not normally part of the holder pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Mark. What about my strange decision - yes, you absolutely right, but I need to get id of item and this is solution that I can feign. Can I ask you give me advice how to do it in right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `setTag()` with a `String`, overwriting the `setTag()` you did earlier with your `ViewHolder`.

You should not need to call `setTag()` with the `String`. You can obtain your `_ID` value at any point by calling `getItemId()` on your `CursorAdapter`.

If you find that answer unacceptable, add a `long id` data member to `ViewHolder` and put the `_ID` there.

Comment: I am ashamed of my inattention; thank you, Mark - second advice help me. I can't use first approach because in _onClick()_ method I don't have position variable.